# From 2 CSV files w/ same header, insert rows randomly into 3rd CSV file in python

Tags: python, arrays, csv, machine-learning, dataset

I'm trying to generate a data set to train/test a neural network; my true values are in one .csv, and false values are in another csv **in python 3**.

I want to randomly mix the two into a third csv.

So I've got three .csv files:

-CSV1 has many more rows than CSV2, both same headers

-Want to write rows randomly from CSV1 and CSV2 into a new CSV3

for example:

CSV1 = [A,B],[C,D],[E,F],[G,H],[I,J],[K, L]

CSV2 = [1,2],[3,4],[5,6]

*run code*

CSV3 = [A,B],[C,D],[1,2],[E,F],[3,4],[G,H],[I,J],[K,L],[5,6]

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you elaborate? Stack Overflow is geared towards **specific problems**, do you think this fits the bill?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Kindly mention what you have tried before posting here.

Assuming you read the 2 csv files into dataframes

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("CSV1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("CSV2.csv")
```

First you concat the 2 dataframes

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
```

Then for randomness, you can shuffle them

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
df3 = shuffle(df3)
```

Note :  you may need to reset your indexes after shuffling:

```
df3.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. I tried what you suggested.However my generated data, referred to as 'df3', comes out weird when I try pd.DataFrame(df3).to_csv("df3.csv") it seems all the rows and columns are messed up.